# Find non-blank cells and copy the information

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find non-blank cells and copy the information from that cell and the cell beside, then paste in last free cell

Excel example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sheet is set up exactly as the image you posted, this should work.

```
Sub combine_rows()

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("B5:B" & lastrow)
    End With

    Count = lastrow + 1
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = cell.Value
            cell.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Count) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```